# How to run a C# project without the project file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have an C# source code of some software my company is using. This source code contains .xaml, .cs files, and one: `App.config`, `packages.config`. However there is no main project file that I can open in Visual Studio.

The original source code can not be found, and the programmer who made it has left the company long ago.

My question is - can I open such a project in C# somehow, without the main project file, so that I could make some changes and compile this application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create a new WPF application project and [add the existing files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9f4t9t92%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You can compile the code using the c# compiler `csc` (which you can find in the .NET Framework installation folder), or just create a new project in Visual studio and add the WPF files to it. The last option is the easiest one.

Comment: You _can_ go the `csc` way, but compiling multiple files with many framework references can prove to be a slight pain to get working. The [C# compiler also doesn't understand XAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970678%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: @CodeCaster: I agree. If you love to do it the hard way, that is an option. That's why I said: "the last one is the easiest option."